# Adding subdomains to cherokee web server over tor as listener

Tags: configuration, onion-services

as topic says.

How to configure cherokee web server to handle subdomains on my onion domain?

You may be interested about [this](https://gist.github.com/mtigas/565718bbb928ce439e95) to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

In `Vservers` tab (between `General` and `Sources` tabs) I choosed small "plus" button (under cherokee's logo), then I clicked `Redirect to other page` for example, next called my subdomain test.xxxxyyyyzzzz.onion, created `phpinfo()` in `index.php`, and it works!